# how to host and schedule python script on aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently working on a enhancement where there is a requirement where  i need to host  python scripts on aws and schedule the python script on top of scheduler.

As part of this , i have created a linux ec2 instance , added python dependencies to the instance, created the directory ,loaded the python files and i was able to run from the instance.

Even i tried scheduling the scripts via cron job . This approach was succesfull.

Can some one  confirm , if this is the right approach of hosting python files in as and schdeuling the python files to run on specific time whenever  needed.

Is there any other alternative approach of hosting  python files in aws and scheduling the python script run other than cron job ?

Note: The python files are complex and it takes huge time to complete.

Welcoming your thoughts on the above question.

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: Depends. Sadly you haven't provided any relevant info about your "python scripts". What are they, how log they run for, how frequently, what they do, how much CPU, RAM they require, what dependencies they use, how much disk they need, etc.

Comment: Hi Marcin, 
The python files handles inbound and outbound transfer from different data source and hence it take more time to complete the task .if i am able to host and schedule a simple python file depending upon the complexity i can check in the CPU, RAM and how much disk size i require.

Comment: "more time" how much? hours? days? minutes? Can you be specific?

Comment: Lets say my python scripts takes 3 hrs to complete to complete execution

Comment: Marcin,  may i know how can we  host the python file on aws ecs and run the python file on ecs .

Comment: You have to make a docker container out of it.

Comment: You might want to Stop the instance when the job is complete and start it again later. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community ‍‍](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: Hi John , One quick question ,   the right way of storing python files in ec2 instance ?how can i shcedule a job other than cron job to run the script from ec2?

Comment: Yes  Marcin, . Not sure how to approach this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your scripts take 3 hours to execute, the other option than EC2, is to run them on ECS as docker containers, through [Scheduling Amazon ECS tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduling_tasks.html).